# An error by copying procedure in an other workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I have copied a workbook as a test version. I have wrote and tested a code and it has worked perfectly, but after copying it into my actual workbook vba gives an "object variable or with..." error. I have checked the workbook's/sheet's names. I didn't make any other changes in the test workbook.

Comment: You need to give more details about the code if you want someone else to help. At least starting by sharing the line of code which fails (and the lines above if possible, or at least the lines where you declare/set the variables contained in the guilty line of code.

Comment: The same code works in four worksheets, but doesn't in three others. Worksheets are identical. No one line was shown as fail.

Comment: What is the line failing and what is the error?

Comment: Object variable or with block variable not set. This is just a popup window, wich doesn't tell, in what line the error is.

Comment: That's a run-time error, it's impossible it doesn't tell you where the line is. Did you click on the button "Debug" when you get the error?

Comment: There wasn't "Debug" button, but now after runing into an other copy it shows "Do until c" line. And if I say, than it is possible!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On my first view i think, that there is the Problem with the Condition for the Do Loop. The Problem is, that **c** is a Range and not a String, so i would check c like this:

`Do Until Not c Is Nothing And c.Address <> FirstAddr`

And i would change

```
Dim WS As Worksheet: Set WS = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("La")
```

to

```
Dim WS As Worksheet: Set WS = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("La")
```

Beacause there are cahnges, that you will get the Wrong Workbook. If you Intrestet why this is so, you can read it her: [VBA ACTIVEWORKBOOK VS THISWORKBOOK](http://analystcave.com/vba-tip-day-activeworkbook-vs-thisworkbook/)

Comment: I have already changed the workbook's name. Vba doesn't still like the new "do until" or the "c" object